# How many injective linear maps are there from $V$ to $W$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $p$ be prime so that $k=\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ is a finite field. Let $V$ be a $d$-dimensional vector space over $k$ and $W$ an $e$-dimensional vector space over $k$.

My Attempt: there are $p^{ed}$ linear maps from $V$ to $W$, a linear map is defined by how it acts on basis vectors and for the map to be injective each $f(v_i)$ must be linearly independent.

so the options for the first $f(v_1)$ can go to any $W$ of order $p^e$ the next can go to $W/\operatorname{span}(f(v_1))$ which has order $p^{e-1}$ and so on up to the $d$'th basis vector. multiplying each of these gives us $p^{ed-\sum_{i=0}^{d-1}i}$

I am not sure if I am getting correct cardinality for each subspace.

sorry for the messy solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is reasonable, but you seem to get some details wrong.
To begin, you should assume that $e\geq d$, otherwise there won't be any injective maps. The resulting formula should somehow reflect that.
The vector space $W$ has $p^e$ elements, but not every element is a legit image of $v_1$: if you map $v_1$ to $0\in W$, then the map $f$ is defintely **not** injective.
Afterwards you get it right: $v_i$ can be mapped to $W\setminus \operatorname{span}\{f(v_1),\dots,f(v_{i-1}\}$. In the case of $i=1$, this is exactly $W\setminus \{0\}$. So we have to count the elements of $\mathrm{span}\{f(v_i),\dots,f(v_{i-1})\}$. This is an $(i-1)$-dimensional vector space, so it consists of $p^{i-1}$ elements. So for each $v_i$, we have $p^e-p^{i-1}$ possibilities, **not** $p^{e-i+1}$.
To conclude, the total possibilities are, by multiplying, $(p^{e}-p^{0})\cdot(p^{e}-p^{1})\cdot\dots\cdot (p^{e}-p^{d-1})$.